# Should I be concerned about the cracking on this exterior brick wall?

Tags: exterior, brick

I recently purchased this house so I am learning something new about home ownership everyday. Today I noticed this crack on my exterior brick wall. Not sure if this should be a cause for concern or if this is something I can patch up myself? Any thoughts on if this is something I should get fixed asap/have a contractor do or is it something I can patch up myself?

This house was built in 1954 and I'm in the North East specifically NJ

[image: picture of crack in bricks]

[image]